# rowSums in all objects of a list with R

Tags: r

I have a big list and I would like to do the `rowSums` of each line in every object of this list.

Here is what I have:

```
> DFTYPE
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
  DGDG.36.5 DGDG.36.6
1  978.4906  3585.613
1 1280.9531  8740.503
1 1228.3969  6082.900
1 5245.2437 18104.022
1    0.0000   827.650

[[1]][[2]]
  DGDG.36.5 DGDG.36.6
2    0.0000  917.5844
2  513.5063  976.2344
2  516.5781 1540.6000
2  838.5406 3486.5563
2 1146.8812 3962.2906
2    0.0000 1050.5281

[[1]][[3]]
  DGDG.36.5 DGDG.36.6
3 1755.0656 10924.975
3  713.2969  4681.759
3  946.1094  3319.722
3 1569.5281  6531.266
3 1827.9156 10501.375
3    0.0000  1973.325


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
  MGDG.34.4 MGDG.34.5 MGDG.34.6 MGDG.36.4 MGDG.36.5 MGDG.36.6
1   891.950  1463.695  14266.34     0.000  1368.040  5015.425
1  2596.695  4228.470  38945.15  1531.350  5617.475 14647.965
1  1536.595  3273.335  30895.44  1610.060  4415.735 11106.930
1  4471.495  9894.595  71023.04  4086.105  9536.450 24968.695

[[2]][[2]]
  MGDG.34.4 MGDG.34.5 MGDG.34.6 MGDG.36.4 MGDG.36.5 MGDG.36.6
2         0       0.0  2158.405      0.00  1478.710  2350.265
2         0       0.0  1409.740      0.00  1776.775  2110.440
2         0       0.0  1910.240      0.00  1044.570  2410.740
2         0     913.5  4558.720   1071.78  1499.770  3616.110
2         0       0.0  7980.890   1993.40  1044.855  8468.875
2         0       0.0  1593.260    792.46     0.000  1019.770

[[2]][[3]]
  MGDG.34.4 MGDG.34.5 MGDG.34.6 MGDG.36.4 MGDG.36.5 MGDG.36.6
3  1225.095  1994.225  20028.34  1728.695  3503.870 11717.955
3   948.865  1284.680   9522.01   487.985  1702.520  4291.785
3     0.000  1396.415  10216.45  1062.240  1438.825  5163.490
3  1077.845  2422.845  20380.78  2904.935  3147.180  8760.835
3  1135.710  3821.430  29022.75  1555.960  3652.580 12318.555
3     0.000   870.055  12322.73     0.000  1652.525  5136.380
```

I then create a new list to get the result of the sum:

```
> DFttt<-list()
> DFttt<-rowSums(DFTYPE)
Error in rowSums(DFTYPE) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a list called `List` as follows:

```
set.seed(1)    
List <- list(list(matrix(rnorm(10), ncol=2), matrix(rnorm(10), ncol=2)),
                 list(matrix(rnorm(10), ncol=2), matrix(rnorm(10), ncol=2)))
lapply(List, function(x) lapply(x, rowSums)) 

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] -1.44692219  0.67107238 -0.09730391  2.17106215  0.02411938

[[1]][[2]]
[1]  1.4668476  0.3736530  0.3225956 -1.3934787  1.7188322


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1]  0.8628486  0.6263408 -1.3961874 -2.4675018  1.0377673

[[2]][[2]]
[1]  0.9436850 -0.4970777  0.3283582  1.0462203 -0.6138838
```

Comment: Thanks also Jilber, same answer, same timing (by 7sec) :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you will need a double `lapply`.

With the following data :

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=2:6)
df2 <- data.frame(u=3:7,v=4:8)
mylist <- list(list(df, df2),list(df,df2))
mylist

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
  x y
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4
4 4 5
5 5 6

[[1]][[2]]
  u v
1 3 4
2 4 5
3 5 6
4 6 7
5 7 8


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
  x y
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4
4 4 5
5 5 6

[[2]][[2]]
  u v
1 3 4
2 4 5
3 5 6
4 6 7
5 7 8
```

You can use :

```
lapply(mylist, function(l) lapply(l, rowSums))
```

Which gives :

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1]  3  5  7  9 11

[[1]][[2]]
[1]  7  9 11 13 15


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1]  3  5  7  9 11

[[2]][[2]]
[1]  7  9 11 13 15
```

Comment: I beat you by 7 sec ;) +1 for you :D

Comment: @Jilber Grrr... With the exact same answer :)

Comment: +1, although I hate double lapply loops...just like double for loops.

Comment: Guys you are so fast to answer, thanks you very much for your efficiency!

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not reproducible, but something like:

```
DFttt = lapply(DFTYPE, rowSums)
```

should to the trick.

Comment: It's a list of list. I don't think this'll work unless you do `unlist(DFTYPE, recursive=F)`. Still it'd give you a list as output, not a list of list.

Comment: I understand that. The only reason I pointed it out is because your code will give the **exact** error the OP had while running `rowSums(DFttt)`; `'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions`.

Comment: You are right, but the question did not have a reproducible example and I was lazy ;).